# "he has a good eye" or "he has good eyes" which one is correct?

Tags: expressions

When I want to express he is sensible or insightful, can I say "he has a good eye." or "he has good eyes"?

Comment: If you see should see the "insufficient text" warning again, please consider adding a couple of example sentences rather than an unnecessary sentence about unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your phrases are correct but have different meanings.

Without any other context, your phrases literally mean

> he has **a** good eye
>   *he has* ***one*** *good eye*
>
> he has good eyes
>   *both his eyes are good*

Neither really express sensibility nor insightfulness which might be expressed as

> he has *a good understanding of*
>   he has *a good grasp of*

Having an *eye for something* is to be able to appreciate the visual aesthetics of *something*

> he has *a good eye for* design layout
>   he has *a good eye for* landscape painting
>   he has *a good eye for* catching continuity flaws in movies

this is usually shortened to

> he has *an eye for* design layout

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is *X has a good eye for Y*, but the "for" is really important here as well as "good eye".

Saying *X has good eyes* literally means that X's eyes are good.

If you say "X has good eyes for Y" it will likely be understood as "X has a good eye for Y", though.